# add number to adjacent column and increment baed on match bash awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to add a second column of data to a set of coordinates  (one line each), that groups those coordinates together based on a re-occuring string or delimiter (male_position).

Here is an example  dataset:

```
male_position
0.0
0.0
2.2
3.0
4.5
male_position
0.0
1.2
20.2
male_position
1.0
2.0
```

Id like to add a grouping ID to the next column:

```
script.awk example.file
male_position  1
0.0  1  
0.0  1
2.2  1
3.0  1
4.5  1
male_position  2
0.0  2
1.2  2
20.2  2 
male_position  3
1.0  3
2.0  3
```

Im not quite where to start, but think awk would get it done. I can add consecutive numbers(by line) in a column with `awk '$2=(FNR FS $2)' myFile` for example , but that obviously doesn't get it done in terms of grouping the coordinates based on the match/delimiter and then ticking up at each match.